# My android app shows [object Promise] using Nativescript

Tags: firebase, nativescript

I cannot show my data from my firebase on my app. I am really new to this and I don't know what to do. I can't find any solution for this on the internet.

This is my typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from "@angular/router";

import { Item } from "./item";
import { ItemService } from "./item.service";
import { EventData } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";
import { Label } from "tns-core-modules/ui/label";
import { listener } from "@angular/core/src/render3";


const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
const firebaseWebApi = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase/app");

@Component({
    selector: "ns-details",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./item-detail.component.html",
})
export class ItemDetailComponent implements OnInit {

item: Item;
public oneway;

public stuff = firebaseWebApi.database().ref("/WaterStatus")
        .once("value")
        .then(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result)))
        .catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error));   

constructor(
    private itemService: ItemService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
    this.item = this.itemService.getItem(id);

    var onChildEvent = function(oneway) {
        console.log("Water Status: " + JSON.stringify(oneway.value));
      };

      // listen to changes in the /users path
      firebase.addChildEventListener(onChildEvent, "/WaterStatus").then(
        function(listenerWrapper) {
          var path = listenerWrapper.path;
          var listeners = listenerWrapper.listeners;
        }
      );





   firebase.getValue('/WaterStatus')
      .then(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result)))
      .catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error));
}

}
```

and this is my html:

```
<ActionBar title="Details" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" class="page">
    <FlexboxLayout class="m-15">
        <Label class="h2" [text]="item.id + '. '"></Label>
        <Label class="h2" [text]="item.name"></Label>


    </FlexboxLayout>
    <Label class="h3" [text]="item.role"></Label>
    <!-- <Button text="Tap Me!" tap="onTap" class="btn btn-primary btn-active"></Button> -->
    <br>
    <br>
    <Label class="h3 p-15" text='{{oneway}}' textWrap="true">{{oneway}}</Label>
    <Label class="h3 p-15" text='{{stuff}}' textWrap="true"></Label>
    <Label class="h3 p-15" text='{{last}}' textWrap="true">{{last}}</Label>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

How can I show my data on my app?

Some say that I should do Promise resolve but I don't really know how to integrate it with that.

screenshot:

[screenchot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brATt.png)

Comment: Where do you see `[object Promise]`? Do you have a Playground sample for this?

Comment: I don't think I have a playground sample of it. I'm still earning nativescript and it's my first time to deal with stuff like this.

Comment: I'll update my post with a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, the `[object Promise]` comes from `<Label class="h3 p-15" text='{{stuff}}' textWrap="true"></Label>` (please confirm by removing the other tables or adding a different color to this label).

In fact, `stuff` is initialized as a promise. Instead, you have to remove that initialization, and inside `ngOnInit()`, do:

```
firebaseWebApi.database().ref("/WaterStatus")
    .once("value")
    .then(result => {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(result)));
         this.stuff = result; // or result.something?
    })
    .catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error));
```

I am not a firebase expert, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. This helps a lot. 